# case-insensitive search in EJB QL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejbql, ejb-2.x

This looks really simple and I can't believe I haven't found a solution myself. I have a bean named PersonBean, which has a name. Now I want to write a finder method that takes a string and looks for people with that string in their name, case-insensitively. Here is my current EJB QL:

```
SELECT OBJECT(p)
FROM Person p
WHERE (p.name LIKE ?1)
```

I have 2 problems with this:

1. I want the search to be case-insensitive (the above is case-sensitive) and I can't find something like `lower()` or `upper()` in EJB QL. What can I do to have that behavior? **UPDATE: I'm using J2EE version 1.4 and glassfish version 2.1, if that matters.**
2. I have to pass an ugly string to the method, i.e `findByString("%john%")`. Is there a way to write the EJB QL so that I can pass something like `findByString("john")`?

Comment: There is nothing about JPA in this question (JPA has been introduced in Java EE 5 and EJB 3.0). So please don't tag it with JPA.

Comment: I didn't, maybe somebody edited to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second question, there is a `CONCAT` function in EJB QL 2.1, so I think the following should work:

<del>WHERE (p.name LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(?1, '%')))</del>

**Edit:** The above does not work because the ql grammer only allows literal strings and input parameters in a `LIKE` expression, which is really limiting. It should be possible to achive the same effect by using the `LOCATE` function like this:

```
WHERE LOCATE(p.name, ?1) <> 0
```

Comment: thanks, actually it is `WHERE LOCATE(?1, p.name) <> 0`, and if used in an xml file like `ejb-jar.xml` it has to be `WHERE LOCATE(?1, p.name) &lt;&gt; 0`

Answer (score 2):

EJB-QL as used in EJB 2.x entity beans (not to be confused with JPQL as used in JPA and EJB3 entity beans) is extremely limited. Altough there were [some additions](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1321184/EJB-21-adds-new-functionality-to-EJB-QL-Monson-Haefels-Guide-to-Enterprise-JavaBeans) to the language in EJB 2.1 there are to my beliefs no upper/lower functions.

I don't know what container your running in but JBoss has made some extensions to EJB-QL (called JBossQL) and features a **UCASE** function.